# Need help with updating a SQL Server query (within a stored procedure)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm very very very new to using stored procedures and I've been tasked with updating one. Within the stored procedure, I need to update the following query:

```
update si_systemdetail  
set status = 'Production'  
where systemname in (select distinct systemname 
                     from @systemHistory 
                     where status = 'Production')`
```

Instead of updating the status to `Production`, I need to either update it to `Production` or `Production w/o Application`.  The `@systemHistory` is a temp table that is populated by xml data and there is also a `StatusHistory` table that contains the value I need for the status `Production w/o Application`.

Basically I need to set status equal to either `Production` or `Production w/o Application` when `systemname` in this other table equals `Production` or `Production w/o Application` accordingly.

Can I even do this in one statement or do I need to make two statements, one to account for the `Production` and the other to account for the `Production w/o Application`?

If you need further information of if I haven't explained this well enough, please let me know.  I really want to learn how to do this.

TIA,
Tom

Comment: systemname is the common field.

Comment: SO wont let me answer this question until it has been posted for 8 hours so I'll update this thread later.  Until then, I think I was making this more difficult than it needed to be.  Below is what I ended up doing:

`update si_systemdetail  
set status = 'Production'
where systemname in (select distinct systemname from @systemHistory where newstatus = 'Production')  
update si_systemdetail
set status = 'Production w/o Appl'
where systemname in (select distinct systemname from @systemHistory where newstatus = 'Production w/o Appl')

if(@@error <> 0)
begin
rollback transaction
return 1
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was making this more difficult than it needed to be.

`update si_systemdetail
set status = 'Production'
where systemname in (select distinct systemname from @systemHistory where newstatus = 'Production')
update si_systemdetail
set status = 'Production w/o Appl'
where systemname in (select distinct systemname from @systemHistory where newstatus = 'Production w/o Appl')

if(@@error <> 0)
begin
rollback transaction
return 1
end`

Answer (score 0):

This would need to be done in two statements unless there is some key to relate the three tables (si_systemdetail, @systemHistory, @SystemName). If there IS a field that you can join these three tables on (ie.... Guid or Some sort of ResourceID) then you could do it in one.

With Relation:

```
UPDATE sysd
SET status = 
CASE
    WHEN sh.SystemName OR stah.SystemName = 'Production' THEN 'Production'
    WHEN stath.SystemName = 'Production w/o Application' THEN 'Production w/o Application'
   ELSE [Default_Value_Here]
 END
FROM si_systemdetail sysd
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [key],systemname 
            FROM @systemHistory 
            WHERE status = 'Production'
   ) sh
    ON sysd.[Key] = [sh.Key]
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [key],systemname 
            FROM @StatusHistory 
            WHERE status IN ('Production', 'Production w/o Application')
   ) stath
    ON sysd.[Key] = stath.[Key]
```

Without Relation :

```
update si_systemdetail  
set status = 'Production'  
where systemname IN (select distinct systemname 
                 from @systemHistory 
                 where status = 'Production')`

update si_systemdetail  
set status = 
CASE
   WHEN status = 'Production w/o Application' THEN 'Production w/o Application'
  ELSE 'Production'
END
WHERE systemname IN (select distinct systemname 
                 from @statusHistory 
                 where status IN ('Production', 'Production w/o Application')
```

Comment: I didn't even think about using CASE.  Your second example might be all I need.  I'll check this out.